# How to prevent method run()?

Tags: java

I try to learn threads and I have a problem. Since the run() method is public() access, so anyone who can refer to my class instance, can use it. So I want to prevent it and there is a way to use anonymous inner class. **But I heard that It can be done by using currentThread and compare it with intended thread.** How can I achieve this?

Assume this:

```
class OnlyConcept implements Runnable {

  OnlyConcept() {

  new Thread(this).start();
}

public void run() {

// call methods or do something meaningful
}

}
```

Comment: You could use a inner or anonymous instance of `Runnable` instead

Comment: Are you concerned with security? If so, you will certainly not solve the issue by making it impossible for another programer who has access to your class to call a given method.

Comment: You cannot prevent hat your `run` method gets called, because an attacker can use reflection. You can only prevent that the code is run accidentally. But even that will probably not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of ways how you can ensure your Thread is only used by the correct class.
One of the better solutions is to hide the implementation from other classes. You could e.g. make the constructor of your `Runnable` package private, or hide the whole thing as a private class in another class of yours.

One of the worse approaches is to check for some stuff once your thread/runnable executes.
`Thread.currentThread()` gives you access to the current thread. With that, you can easily access the `name` or some other property of that thread and stop execution of your special thread. This solution however is rather inferior to the other solutions. If your code relies on thread names and funny stuff like that, you are likely to run into problems later (e.g. if you want to execute your code in parallel in two distinct threads.

Restricting access to your code by using visibility modifiers, encapsulating your class in a different class is a cleaner approach. Use this if you have any chance.

Comment: Thanks guys, it really helps to overcome some issues.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do two things:

1. name your thread, by passing a name to a `Thread` constructor
2. check `Thread.currentThread.getName()` on the first line of your `run` method, throw some suitable exception like `RuntimeException` if it isn't right.

This is not 100% foolproof because someone else could name their thread the same as yours.

Comment: I suggest comparing the threads by reference, that is `theOnlyAllowedThread == Thread.currentThread()`.

Comment: @RolandIllig which would then only require a bit of reflection to change `theOnlyAllowedThread`. If someone absolutely wants to use stuff he should not use, it is damn hard to prevent it. Why not just design the class according to OO principles and hope the potential user starts to think before is trying to use that code.

Comment: Thanks Robin, it looks something what I need to know.

Comment: “someone else could name their thread the same as yours” Well, “someone else” can also rename your thread to something different and watch your surprise. But “someone else” can do a lot if things if you allow “someone else” to execute arbitrary code within your JVM without a `SecurityManager`. Renaming threads is the most harmless…

Comment: @RolandIllig I am assuming that this Runnable is to be passed to a Thread constructor to create a new thread. If so, how do you know what `theOnlyAllowedThread` is before it exists?